# TypeError element.offset is not a function in JS file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, function, typeerror, scrolltop

I have a site that uses a Zendesk support chat widget, but the widget doesn't work on mobile devices. In the console, I can see that in one of our JS files there is the error:

TypeError: element.offset is not a function

This then triggers other errors in the web widget code, causing it to not load.

In our JS file, however, it appears that "element" is defined, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

This is where I think element is defined:

```
$.tools.validator.fn('#some_code', "This is the text", function(input, value) {
var element = $('#' + input.attr('data-match-field'));
return element.size() == 0 || element.val() == value;
});
```

This is where the error is happening further down in the same file:

```
function scrollTo(element) {
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:element.offset().top}, 'ease');
}
```

I'm hoping you all can help me figure out what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where's the `scrollTo` function being called? maybe you are passing an HTMLElement instead of a jquery object (you can try with `$(element).offset()`)

Comment: I actually didn't find any uses of the scrollTo function. I tried commenting it out in that one specific file, and things seem to be working. I did try changing it to $(element).offset(), but I still got the same error.

Comment: thanks arieljuod, i passed a class and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

After prompting from @arieljuod, I searched for instances of scrollTo and didn't find any in use. I ended up commenting out that function and the errors went away.